# Google Sheets Calculate Data and Keep it as it is Even if Source Data is Deleted

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has normal calculations as stuff. Sheet 2 has a FILTER formula to extract some data from Sheet1. That extracted data will now be deleted in Sheet 1. This causes the issue in Sheet 2.

Now what I want to do is, extracted data in Sheet 2 should remain as it is without any errors and I want to delete that data in Sheet 1. This process will be happening time and again with different rows in Sheet 1 to Sheet 2. As yes, one more thing is that I do not want any circular reference errors. And would be great if done without a script.

Simple copy paste won't be practical as its a large data. Need this to be automized.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: This is not possible as there is no formula that allows to copy only the values of cells, you can double check it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) however this could be achieved by using apps script, would you be willing to use a code for this end?

Comment: Yes.. If it's not possible with formula then script I am willing to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment it is currently not possible to make a copy of values to a different sheet though formulas alone, you can keep an eye on the full [list of formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) to see if anything like this gets added in the future.

With that being said the code itself to copy these values is quite simple, here are some options (both are assuming that the name of the sheet with the filter is "Sheet2" so please make sure to change "Sheet 2" to the actual name of the sheet where the filter happens.):

- Option 1: This code creates a new sheet and writes the data of Sheet 2 on a newly created sheet however this makes the sheet more resource consuming but in turn makes the data easier to read.

```js
function copyValues() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.insertSheet().getName()
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  var values =ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(range).setValues(values)
  }
```

- Option 2: This code adds the data from Sheet 2 to Sheet 3 (This means that Sheet 3 just keeps growing as more data is added), the good thing is that this will make the Spreadsheet less resource consuming but in turn makes the data more difficult to read.

```js
function copyValues() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values =ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").appendRow(values[i])
  }
  }
```

The last piece of this would be to add a trigger, I'm not quite sure how would you need this data saved but you can add these extra lines of code to any of the options you choose to create a custom menu on Spreadsheet for you to have a button to click to choose when to run the backup.

```js
  function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Backup')
      .addItem("Run Backup","copyValues")
      .addToUi();
}
```

Here is how the custom menu will look:

[image]

Please keep in mind that you need to close the sheet and re-open it after you added the custom menu code, sheets will also take a couple of seconds to load the menu after each time you re-open it.

if you would like to choose a different kind of trigger like an "onOpen" or "onEdit" you can do so from the apps script interface here:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Option 1 is out of question as it makes a new sheet everytime is not what I want to have. However, I have a problem in option 2.

Whenever I run the script, it catches the entire sheet again from Sheet2 and saves in sheet3 again. So here the whole data is reprinted again and again. And also as in sheet1 (the source) have the data deleted, sheet2 will show NA error in the filter formula. So the reprinted data will also show NA.

Isn't it possible that the data already printed should not be printed again and continue printing after the last printed row? That way there are no duplicates.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this outcome, and I'm sorry the code didn't turn out the way you needed it. The way I understand it is that you delete the data, then the script runs and this somewhat generates duplicated entries, since the data was deleted before the I thought that there should not be duplicates, would it be possible for you to share some sample data and examples of how it looks right now and how you would like it to look instead?

I bet we can make it work!

Comment: Thanks for the help. With the help of Chatgpt and you I was able to solve this. Thank you once again :)